# Realm, React Native embedded object example

Tags: typescript, react-native, realm

I'm looking for any concrete examples of using realm with React Native + TypeScript using embedded objects.

Usually you can provide a partial object of properties to send to realm for CRUD operations:

```
realm.write(() => {
  realm.create<SomeSchemaObject>(
    SchemaObject.schema.name,
    {
        id: 1,
        someListType: ??? // where someListType is an embedded schema object.
    },
    UpdateMode.Modified
  )
}
```

With typescript and providing say an array of partial properties for the embedded object, I get type errors. I've scoured the Realm-JS repo and the documentation, but there don't seem to be any examples of using typescript and embedded objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should have dug a little harder on my own before asking the question. Anyhow, I managed to figure it out. For a little setup, I don't use realm entities directly in my application, I actually convert those entities on the way out to DTOs. My DTO's all implement an interface that defines a method to get the property object for insert/update operations. Previously I was typing that return object to be Partial when in fact I should have been using RealmInsertionModel.

Hopefully this will be of some help to someone else.

```
toRealmInsertionModel(): RealmInsertionModel<UserSessionEntity> {
    // In my schema UserSessionEntity has an embedded list of ScopeEntity.
    const entities: RealmInsertionModel<ScopeEntity>[] = this.scopes.map(
      scopeDto => scopeDto.toRealmInsertionModel(),
    );

    return {
      id: this.id,
      accessToken: this.accessToken,
      refreshToken: this.refreshToken,
      idToken: this.idToken,
      tokenType: this.tokenType,
      scopes: entities,
    };
}
```